# Repulsion b/w two flat cylindrical magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

Given 2 identical 'flat' cylindrical permanent magnets, $A_1$ and $A_2$. The radius, height and weight of each magnet is denoted by $R$, $H$ and $W$ respectively. (magnets are flat implies that $R$ > $H$.) Moreover, $A_2$ has some totally nonmagnetic dead weight ($W_D$) glue on it.

Let's fix $A_1$ face down on the ground, enclosed in a vertical non-magnetic hollow tube of necessary height and radius.

Now, we drop $A_2$ face down from the top of the tube such that both magnets have the same face towards each other ($N-N$ or $S-S$). Since the magnets will repel each other $A_2$ will eventually come to a halt and hover at some height $(h)$ above $A_1$.

**Query 1:** How does $h$ change with changes in:

a. The strength of the magnets (measured as 'Pull Force' in Newton/Kg).

b. The weight $W$ (in Kg).

Can someone please help with a good enough approximate formula?

Comment: The "pull force" quoted by magnet vendors usually refers to the force between a permanent magnet and an unmagnetized ferromagnetic piece of metal (i.e., a piece of steel.)  The force between two permanent magnets cannot necessarily be determined just by knowing the pull force.

Comment: Thank you. If the two magnets are identical they will have the same pull force. So assuming everything else (mass, radius, height etc.) of the magnets remain the same and the only variable is this 'pull force' can't we approximate 'h' w.r.t. the 'pull force'?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I suspect not.  The force with which a magnet attracts a piece of steel will not necessarily be equal to the force with which it attracts another magnet.